# How to select a rectangle from List<Rectangle[]> with Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, linq-to-objects

I have a list of `DrawObject[]`. Each DrawObject has a `Rectangle` property. Here is my event:

```
List<Canvas.DrawObject[]> matrix;

void Control_MouseMove ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
{
    IEnumerable<Canvas.DrawObject> tile = Enumerable.Range( 0, matrix.Capacity - 1)
                                          .Where(row => Enumerable.Range(0, matrix[row].Length -1)
                                                 .Where(column => this[column, row].Rectangle.Contains(e.Location)))
                                          .????;
}
```

I am not sure exactly what my final select command should be in place of the "????". Also, I was getting an error: `cannot convert IEnumerable<int> to bool`.

I've read several questions about performing a linq query on a list of arrays, but I can't quite get what is going wrong with this. Any help?

**Edit:**
Apologies for not being clear in my intentions with the implementation.

I intend to select the `DrawObject` that currently contains the mouse location.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It isn't clear what the expected result is. Sample input / output would help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. I *suspect* you want something like:

```
var drawObjects = from array in matrix
                  from item in array
                  where item.Rectangle.Contains(e.Location)
                  select item;
```

... but maybe not. You haven't shown what you're trying to do with the result of the query, or what `this[column, row]` is there for.

You almost certainly don't want to be using the *capacity* of the list in the first place - it's more likely that you're interested in the `Count`, but using the list as an `IEnumerable<T>` is probably better anyway.

EDIT: Okay, so the above query finds *all* the `drawObjects` where the rectangle contains the given location. You almost certainly want to use something like `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`. For example:

```
var drawObject = (from array in matrix
                  from item in array
                  where item.Rectangle.Contains(e.Location)
                  select item)
                 .SingleOrDefault();

if (drawObject != null) // We found one
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: apologies for not being clear. I want to select the `Canvas.DrawObject` that currently contains the mouse location.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tile = matrix.SelectMany(x => x)
                 .Where(x => x.Rectangle.Contains(e.Location));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
....Select(y => y);
```

But it is hard to really tell what you are doing. And your first `Where` clause will not work since the lambda expression in the clause must result in a bool, but your lambda expression is resulting in a `IEnumerable<T>`. If I'm not all wrong.